# Setting up a long-running task on nodejs

Tags: node.js

In my backend, I have about 5k users. Every day at 12pm UTC, I need to run a background node task, that carries out some real-time calculations on the user's data and sends it to the user by email/sms/notification, etc. This calculation is a bit intensive and takes a few seconds for each user.

Since 10k is a large number, I've created a schedule such that an API endpoint is called to run the task every 1 minute and processes 5 users on every call. The problem with this approach of processing 5 users per minute, is that at this speed it takes 16 hours to process all 5000 users. At the same time, the number of users is growing; soon enough, even 24 hours will not be enough.

What's the alternative? How can I process all these 5k users or even 10k users in a much shorter duration?

Comment: The simple answer is reduce the processing time per user, and process more users at once. To get a useful answer can you provide detail on the process, What's the bottleneck in the processing? Do the users need to be processed serially? Is any of this just waiting that can be made parallel tasks. Maybe some work can be handed off to the database? It's hard to suggest something without the specifics

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing relevant code or you describing in significant detail what exactly this background node task is doing, we can't advise specifically on what approach or approaches you need to take as the answer totally depends upon understanding that task in detail.

If the nodejs background task is CPU bound, then you will need to involve more CPUs in the processing either with child_processes or WorkerThreads.

If the nodejs background tasks is database-limited, then you will need to scale your database to handle more requests in less time or redesign how the relevant data is stored to be more efficient.

If nearly all the processing is asynchronous and not CPU bound and not database-limited, then you perhaps need to be processing N users in parallel.

As with any performance problem, it's not good to guess where the biggest bottleneck is.  **You need to instrument and measure!**  I would suggest that you start by instrumenting the processing of one user to find out exactly where all the time is going.  Then, start with the longest pole in the tent and dive into exactly why it's taking that much time.  See how much you can improve that one item.  Move onto the next one.  Once you've made the processing of a single user as fast as it can be, then work on ways to process N users at a time and make sure your database can scale with that.  By dividing up the users across more processes and processing N at a time in each process, you can scale the calculation work as much as you want.  You will have to make sure that your database can keep up with that additional load from all the separate processes.

Comment: Thanks. I will work on optimizing. One thing that I wanted to know was if it's possible to have a continuous running process, as opposed to calling it every 1 minute and processing 5 users. In a way that this continuously running process processes all 5000 users one by one without taking a break. If yes, how do I setup a continuous running process, that doesn't break things.

Comment: @asanas - I don't understand what you don't know how to do to process all 5000 users.  You would just create a loop, that processes each user one at a time.  When the first one finishes, it starts on the 2nd one.  We CANNOT help more specifically without seeing your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The loop is not a problem. In fact what I have done is a loop, but because each user takes about 2-3 seconds to process, and there are 5000 users to process, the function will timeout. That's what I was asking - how to keep it running without timing out?

Comment: @asanas - I'm done trying to guess what your code looks like and what the problems are with it.  If you want any further help from me, show ALL the relevant code in your question.  You don't seem to understand that we could help 10x more efficiently and 10x more usefully if you showed your code than just trying to describe things in words only.  If you sense a bit of frustration here, you'd be right.  Show your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to share the code. I don't think it's that hard to understand the scenario that I'm trying to present. I'm not even asking for help optimizing my code. It's as simple as imagining a loop that processes some data for lots (and lots) of users. The data that is processed could be a simple math problem or a complex database operation. I don't need help with optimizing that. I just needed help with technical guidance on how to keep the loop running without crashing, irrespective of whether a single user takes 1 second or 100 seconds.

Comment: @asanas - Well, we don't even have any idea what is causing the timeout.  Hard to know how to fix it when we don't even know why there is even a timeout involved here.  You seem to be assuming we know things about your code that you've not described here - thus why we keep asking to see relevant code so we can see for ourselves what exactly is going on.

Comment: Ok, let me prepare a sample mimicking my problem. I'll share it in a couple of days. Really appreciate your help.